# I am getting a Resources$NotFoundException inflating a menu with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, xml, actionbarsherlock, android-logcat

When I try to inflate the menu in the **onCreateOptionsMenu** method, it seems to cause a **Resources$NotFoundException** even though R.java has it generated and it is under the res/menu folder. Here is the code that is causing the exception:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

The XML file I'm trying to inflate (res/menu/mainmenu):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:actionLayout="@string/filter_menuitem"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/filter_menuitem"
/>
```

Red output from LogCat

```
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Filter from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f090012
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2190)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2145)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:872)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:566)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapper.setActionView(MenuItemWrapper.java:230)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:454)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:468)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:190)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:112)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at edu.calpoly.android.lab3.AdvancedJokeList.onCreateOptionsMenu(AdvancedJokeList.java:112)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockActivity.java:184)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:560)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:64)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(SherlockActivity.java:149)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2449)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:418)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:769)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:3015)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4519)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Filter
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2172)
10-31 13:42:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    ... 27 more
```

And my import statements, if it helps

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.*;

import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

Any feedback as to why this exception is being thrown?

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project or restarting eclipse?

Comment: Yeah, numerous times, it still throws the same exception